# Can't identify the source of "Uncaught TypeError: t.apply is not a function" in React app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I just started getting this error in my production app built with create-react-app and I can't figure out where it might be coming from:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.apply is not a function
 at Object.ze (react-dom.production.min.js:54:317)
 at Ue (react-dom.production.min.js:54:471)
 at react-dom.production.min.js:55:35
 at Lr (react-dom.production.min.js:105:68)
 at zr (react-dom.production.min.js:106:380)
 at react-dom.production.min.js:117:104
 at as (react-dom.production.min.js:273:42)
 at je (react-dom.production.min.js:52:375)
 at Ur (react-dom.production.min.js:109:469)
 at Qt (react-dom.production.min.js:74:59)
```

It fires for some reason when I click on any of the input fields in one of my components. It doesn't crash the UI, just quietly shows up in the console. What would be the best practices for identifying the source of an error like this?

Comment: Provide code sample of this component

Comment: I figured out it was an onClick attribute in one of my components getting defined as an empty string instead of a function. Changing `onClick={props.onClick ? props.onClick : "" }` to `onClick={props.onClick ? props.onClick : () => {} }` solved the problem.